# A linux virtual interface that can actually route packets

Tags: linux, networking, ip, routing, ethernet

I have a linux machine with one actual interface that connect to the internet; lets say eth0 192.168.1.108

I need to create a virtual interface that routes traffic through the [eth0] but shows a different ip address [10.10.0.1] based on some access control lists.

I need to create a new virtual device that will have a ip address of 10.10.0.1 for access control purposes.

I've created a dummy device

```
ip link add name acl0 type dummy
ip addr add 10.10.0.1
ip link set dev acl0 up
```

That creates the interface but it doesn't actually route any traffic.

How can I create a virtual device with a specific ip address that will actually route traffic?

Comment: Check https://xyproblem.info/ , looks that's a case of it.

Comment: Yep, what do you want to achieve? "Shows a different IP address": to whom?

Answer (score 3):

Please edit your question and provide details why do you need a second IP and how do you plan to use it for access purposes.

An **interface** doesn't "route traffic". The kernel routes traffic.

1. The only thing a dummy interface is good for is as a placeholder for an IP with no functionality, so applications can bind to it. Plenty of people have made the mistake to assume that it somehow does something, but it doesn't.
2. You can assign multiple IP addresses to the same interface, but then you need to make sure all your applications **bind** to a specific address, or you'll have fun debugging the random effects.
3. Depending on what kind of "access control" you need, a simple way to separate networking for different applications is to use a **network namespace**. Put the "special" application inside the network namespace, then it will act is if it's running on a different machine as far as the network is concerned, so you can give it different settings.

Either use a `macvlan` on your `eth0` to have it use the same interface with a different IP address (or maybe use DHCP to give it an IP), or create a veth-pair between the new namespace and the main network namespace, and then do normal routing.